# Return only the first result of a multiple return values in golang

Tags: go

Absolute newbie question here.

Some functions in Go return more than one value (normally, the value and an error). I was writing a func who return the return value of one of those functions, and even if it is very easy to put the values on variables and return only the first one, I have the doubt if I could do the same in only one line without the extra variable. This is something often uses in other languages like C, Java, C#, Ruby, etc

```
func someFunc (param string) int {
   // do something with the string, not very important
   return strconv.Atoi(param) 
}
```

I know this works

```
func someFunc (param string) int {
   // do something with the string, not very important
   var result int
   result, _ = strconv.Atoi(param)
   return result 
}
```

It is this possible in Go? It is considered a "good practice" (like in Java*)

Note: Before someone say that this technique is not a good practice in Java, clarify that is not important for the question, but some people (like the ones in the company I work) encourage that style.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) for the shortest code to accomplish this goal:

```
func SomeFunc(parm string) int {
    result, _ := strconv.Atoi(param)
    return result
}
```

There is no one line solution without introducing a helper function that accepts two arguments and returns the first.  One of these helper functions would be needed for each combination of types where you want to ignore a value.

Answer (score 9):

Your best possible one-liner is a helper function written as:

```
func first(n int, _ error) int {
    return n
}

func SomeFunc(param string) int {
    return first(strconv.Atoi(param))
}
```

Note that:

- the argument types and positions must match exactly
- the second argument to `first` has the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) (`_`), making it clear that you wish to completely ignore it. [1]

If you **absolutely** don't want to declare a named function, you may use a function literal, but that looks real ugly:

```
func SomeFunc(param string) int {
    return func(n int, _ error) int { return n }(strconv.Atoi(param))
}
```

In general, the helper function is worth it if you have a lot of repetition in your code. Otherwise just use a temp variable, which looks clean and idiomatic:

```
func SomeFunc(param string) int {
    n, _ := strconv.Atoi(param)
    return n
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/X8EOh_JVDDG

---

Once generics will be added to the language in Go 1.18, you will be able to write a helper function that can be used with any return pair and preserve type safety on the first one:

```
func first[T, U any](val T, _ U) T {
    return val
}

func SomeFunc(param string) int {
    return first(strconv.Atoi(param))
}
```

Go2 Playground: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/vLmTuwzrl5o

---

Footnotes:

[1] Keep in mind that in case of `strings.Atoi` the second return value is an error, and ignoring errors *is bad practice*. However there are cases where the success of the operation truly doesn't matter, then it's fine to use `_` to ignore the argument.

Comment: I use these:

func firstOf2[T, U any](val T, _ U) T {
 return val
}

func secondOf2[T, U any](_ T, val U) U {
 return val
}

for oneliners like:

func tzNameToOffset(name string) int {
 return secondOf2(time.Now().In(firstOf2(time.LoadLocation(name))).Zone()) / 60 / 60
}

Thanks for the PROTIP! Golang could do better at addressing multiple return values in oneliners.

Answer (score 1):

While the other languages you mentioned have this capability, it is important to note what happens for invalid input. Java, for example, will throw an exception that you must catch if you want to validate the user input. Do **you** (the you reading this answer, not just the OP) trust the user input to not cause an invalid state in your program should you not handle the error if it is non-nil? If so, then continue on with this answer, otherwise, I strongly urge you to consider proper validation of all returned errors from any function calls to avoid undesired states in your applications.

That said, here is how you would accomplish what you are trying to achieve in two ways for Go 1.18+: generics (for if and only if the returned arguments are consistent), and "any" parameters (if the additional returns vary in type):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func testVariedReturns() (string, error, error, string) {
    return "varied", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test"), "testing"
}

func testConsistentReturns() (string, error, error) {
    return "consistent", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test")
}

func first(first any, rest ...any) any {
    fmt.Printf("first arugment: %v\n", first)
    fmt.Printf("rest of arguments: %v\n", rest)
    return first
}

func firstGeneric[T any](first any, rest ...T) any {
    fmt.Printf("first arugment: %v\n", first)
    fmt.Printf("rest of arguments: %v\n", rest)
    return first
}

func AToINoError(v string) int {
    return first(strconv.Atoi(v)).(int)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", AToINoError("314156"))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", first(testVariedReturns()))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", first(testConsistentReturns()))
    // uncomment the below to cause an error
    // fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", firstGeneric(testVariedReturns()))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", firstGeneric(testConsistentReturns()))
}
```

Simply uncomment the `// fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", firstGeneric(testVariedReturns()))` line to see what happens if you vary the type with generics that only accept matching types for a variable number of parameters.

For prior to Go 1.18, the following should suffice:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func testVariedReturns() (string, error, error, string) {
    return "varied", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test"), "testing"
}

func testConsistentReturns() (string, error, error) {
    return "consistent", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test")
}

func first(first interface{}, rest ...interface{}) interface{} {
    fmt.Printf("first arugment: %v\n", first)
    fmt.Printf("rest of arguments: %v\n", rest)
    return first
}

func AToINoError(v string) int {
    return first(strconv.Atoi(v)).(int)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", AToINoError("314156"))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", first(testVariedReturns()))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", first(testConsistentReturns()))
}
```

And lastly, if you wish to return the nth return of a function, you can do so following ways:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func testVariedReturns() (string, error, error, string) {
    return "varied 2", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test"), "testing"
}

func testConsistentReturns() (string, error, error) {
    return "consistent 2", fmt.Errorf("error"), fmt.Errorf("test")
}

func selectReturn(args ...any) func(returnOffset uint) any {
    return func(returnOffset uint) any {
        if int(returnOffset) >= len(args) {
            fmt.Printf("out of bounds\n")
            return nil
        }
        fmt.Printf("retrieving: %v\n", args[returnOffset])
        fmt.Printf("all arguments: %v\n", args)
        return args[returnOffset]
    }
}

func selectReturnFromArray(args ...any) []any {
    return args
}

func AToINoError(v string) int {
    return selectReturn(strconv.Atoi(v))(0).(int)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", AToINoError("314156"))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", selectReturn(testVariedReturns())(0))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", selectReturn(testConsistentReturns())(0))
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", selectReturnFromArray(testVariedReturns())[0])
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n\n", selectReturnFromArray(testConsistentReturns())[0])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a really stupid way to do this:

```golang
for z:=func(str string, _ error)string{return str};;{return z(strconv.Atoi(param))}
```

It's a worse version of the other one-liner posted here, but I find it far more interesting. It defines a named function, `z`, instead of an anonymous function like the other answer.